# Python datetime & groupby - Creating a new dataframe Summarising the another dataframe according to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas-groupby, boxplot

My goal is to summarise a person's heart rate speed over time, and make a boxplot to visualise it.

Now I have a dataframe with raw data like this:
[image]

```
{'Minute': {0: Timestamp('2015-02-24 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2015-02-24 00:00:30'),
  2: Timestamp('2015-02-24 00:01:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2015-02-24 00:01:30'),
  4: Timestamp('2015-02-24 00:02:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2015-02-24 00:02:30')},
 'heartrate': {0: 66, 1: 68, 2: 70, 3: 72, 4: 75, 5: 79}}
```

And I wanted to create a new dataframe summarising the heart rate statistics according to the minute, here is what I want to have:
[image]

```
{'Hour': {0: '00', 1: '00', 2: '00'},
 'Minute': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2},
 'Max heart rate': {0: 68, 1: 72, 2: 79},
 'Min heart rate': {0: 66, 1: 70, 2: 75},
 'Avg heart rate': {0: 67, 1: 71, 2: 77}}
```

Eventually, I want to use the new dataframe above to plot the heart rate with boxplots and x-axis as time series, like the following one with x-axis as time (minute) and y-axis as heart rate bpm:
[image]

And for the date time part, if there are data of different days like 1 Feb, 2 Feb, 3 Feb, all with the Hour 9pm and minute of 01, how do I differentiate it?

A big thank you to all people who helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': {0: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-24 00:00:00'), 
1: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-24 00:00:30'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-24 
00:01:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-24 00:01:30'), 4: pd.Timestamp('2015- 
02-24 00:02:00'), 5: pd.Timestamp('2015-02-24 00:02:30')}, 'heartrate': 
{0: 66, 1: 68, 2: 70, 3: 72, 4: 75, 5: 79}})

df['Minute'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda minute : minute.minute)
df['Hour'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda hour : hour.hour)
df['Day'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda day : day.day)
df['Month'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda month : month.month)
df['Year'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda year : year.year)
df.groupby(['Year','Month','Day','Hour','Minute']).agg({'heartrate': 
['mean', 'min', 'max']})
```

Comment: Thank you @Vebjørn Gaupset !  Do you think it's possible to make it a new dataframe (like the middle picture above) if not to use groupby?   If I were to plot boxplot of the df, the groupby version may not work well.

Comment: maybe try to replace last line with this:

df.groupby(['Year','Month','Day','Hour','Minute']).agg({'heartrate': 
['mean', 'min', 'max']}).reset_index()

Comment: And if you don't want to keep track of year, month or day you could add 
.drop('Year', inplace =True, axis =1)